# Flask not Running

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

When trying to run my hello.py file it says it can't be imported, was working previously but just stopped, can't work out why

[[image: Below is an imagine of my code and what i entered into the terminal]]

Answer (score 2):

Add the code below in your code. It will work.
And make sure the terminal is the current directory.
(Specify the host and the port based on what ports are open) or just use 127.0.0.1

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True, host="192.168.68.91", port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your image I see your app is under **try** directory, but in terminal you are in home probably. You need to **cd** into **try** or export relative path, like `export FLASK_APP=try.hello`

Answer (score 0):

First you dont have workspace, so your directory is not right. You need to make sure your terminal location is correct first, then set the flask application environment variable like this `export Flask_APP=<your file name or package name>`. Here, you should set it like this `export Flask_APP=hello`, then run the flask cli command `flask run`.

There is a quick way, you can press `F5` and choose to run the flask program and finally fill in the path of your file within vs code.